# Dynamical Systems Periodic Orbits existing

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the nonlinear dynamical system $(1)$ :

$x' = y(1 + x−y^2)$,

$y' = x(1 + y−x^2)$, where $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

(i) Determine the equilibrium points of $(1)$

(ii) Classify the equilibrium points found in part (i)

(iii) Suppose that the equations model an experimental situation such that $x≥0$, $y≥0$
($x$, $y$ could for example be related to the concentrations of chemical species in a chemical reaction). Do periodic orbits exist?

I got:

(i) $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,-1)$, $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$, $(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2,\frac{1+\sqrt5}2)$, $(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2,\frac{1-\sqrt5}2)$

(I am pretty sure these are correct and I haven't missed out any)

(ii) Saddle point, Unstable Spiral, cannot be classified, Unstable Spiral, cannot be classified, Saddle point, Stable Spiral respectively to the order I wrote the equilibrium points.

How do you do (iii)????

Comment: Look at the eigenvalues, det, and the discriminate of the Jacobian. You may want to commit [this](http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/mat332/exhibit/fxdpt2d.html) plot to memory.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure. I typed in wolfram alpha the two equations set to zero and it gave me what I wrote down. Why do you ask?

Comment: OK cool. But I still don't know how to do the third part because we haven't gone through jacobian. I have no idea what that is so we aren't really expected to use it.

Comment: Have you learned any theorems for periodic orbits? For example, any of these: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Periodic_orbit . Lastly, did you do a phase portrait plot as it can be quite revealing to validate the analysis?

Comment: Bendixons negative criterion is the only one tbh

Comment: Question (iii) is odd since, for most initial conditions in the positive quadrant, the solution ends up out of the positive quadrant (the exceptional starting points being the fixed points (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), and the diagonal x=y). Hence this system is ill-suited to model the evolution of some pair of populations.

Comment: Well I think we have to use Bendixon's Negative Criterion which states: For $x'=P(x,y)$, $y'Q(x,y)$. Suppose that on a simply connected closed region D of the phase plane that the expression $\partial P/\partial x+\partial Q/\partial y$ is of fixed sign, then D contains no periodic orbits.

Comment: In our case in part iii, we know that x and y are $\geq0$ and our expression gives us x+y which is going to be at least zero. So it is always going to be positive which I would then conclude that it has no periodic orbits BUT what if x+y is 0. zero is not a positive or negative number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat a comment about (iii), which does not seem to have been taken into consideration: for most initial conditions in the positive quadrant, the solution ends up out of the positive quadrant (the exceptional initial conditions are the fixed points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and the diagonal $x=y$). Hence this system is ill-suited to model the evolution of a pair of populations. Proof:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$
[image]

$$\texttt{streamplot[{y(1+x−y^2),x(1+y−x^2)},{x,-0.5,3},{y,-0.5,3}]}$$